# Why am I having problems while training spacy for NER on two different datasets which are on same formats?

Tags: python, spacy

I had a dataset for NER which wasn't a very good one. I found a new dataset for my NER. I parse it and bring it to the required format by spaCy for training but while training after the first iteration losses goes to `1.7533640989547781e-13`s. Then when I try to evaluate it's not able to detect any entities.

I realized that when I give bigger dataset the loss value doesn't become 0 after the first iteration.
When I train on my previous dataset it works without a problem but when I try to evaluate it with my new dataset it can't detect anything.
So I assume the problem is in the dataset which I still couldn't find.

Data in my old dataset looks like this:

```
test1 = 
[
    (
        'Corina Casanova , İsviçre Federal Şansölyesidir .',
        {
            'entities': [
                    (0, 6, 'PERSON'), 
                    (7, 15, 'PERSON'), 
                    (18, 25, 'LOCATION')
                ]
        }
    ), 
    (
        "Casanova , İsviçre Federal Yüksek Mahkemesi eski Başkanı , Nay Giusep'in pratiğinde bir avukat olarak çalıştı .", 
        {
            'entities': [
                    (11, 18, 'ORGANIZATION'), 
                    (19, 26, 'ORGANIZATION'), 
                    (27, 33, 'ORGANIZATION'), 
                    (34, 43, 'ORGANIZATION')
                ]
        }
    )
]
```

Data from new dataset:

```
test2 =
[
    (
        "Müzik Şenliği 'ne hazırlanın  POZİTİF ve Açık Radyo  işbirliğiyle düzenlenecek olan  İstanbul  Müzik Şenliği 2 , müzikseverlere Aralık ayında merhaba demeye hazırlanıyor",
        {
            'entities': [
                    (30, 52, 'ORGANIZATION'), 
                    (85, 94, 'LOCATION')
                ]
        }
    ), 
    (
        "Geçtiğimiz yıl ilki büyük heyecan yaratan , müzik ile ilgili her kesimden insanı tek bir çatı altında , keyifli bir ortamda buluşturmayı , müziği ve müzisyeni ön plana çıkarmayı , Türk müziğinin binbir tınısını dünyaya yayabilmek için gerekli ortamı yaratabilmeyi amaçlayan Şenlik yine  Askeri Müze ve Kültür Sitesi 'nde ağırlayacak konuklarını ", 
        {
            'entities': [
                    (287, 316, 'LOCATION')
                ]
        }
    )
]
```

Comment: in my personal experience, spacy doesn't work well with long lines. so I try to keep the sentence length to a maximum of 200.

Comment: I tried keeping it at a maximum of 200 characters as well, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was on my new dataset annotations the ending character included empty space. Which was the cause of the problem.